# Jquery code inside php variable (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables

I'm using Mixitup (jquery) and making use of a callback function:

```
callbacks: {
    onMixEnd: function(state){
        ... 
        $('.equal').matchHeight();
    }
},
```

Now I'd like to change the code inside a variable, so it will become like this:

```
callbacks: {
    onMixEnd: function(state){
        ... 
        $matched_heights    
    }
},
```

The reason for this is because I only want this extra jquery code to be only available inside a specific theme.

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();

    if ('externaltheme' == $theme->name || 'externaltheme' == $theme->parent_theme) {   

        //jquery code e.g.
        $matched_heights = $('.equal').matchHeight();

    }  else {
        $matched_heights = '';  
    }
```

Needless to say, this will throw an error. Therefore my following question: 
How to modify `$matched_heights = $('.equal').matchHeight();` so that it will work?

Comment: Quote it as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the theme name as a class to the body tag

### functions.php

Add a new class via filter

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_custom_body_classes' );
function my_custom_body_classes( $classes )
{
  $theme = wp_get_theme();

  if ('externaltheme' == $theme->name || 'externaltheme' == $theme->parent_theme) {   
      $classes[] = 'externaltheme';
  }

  return $classes;
}
```

### header.php

Make sure that your theme adds the classes to the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

### Javascript

Then you can do this in JS:

```
callbacks: {
    onMixEnd: function(state){
        if ( $(body).hasClass('externaltheme') ) {
            $('.equal').matchHeight();
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm afraid the jquery code must be added inside `onMixEnd: function(state){...}`  It has to do with the Mixitup jquery script Im using.